# PHP Error when trying to insert a collections into MongoDB with CodeIgniter and MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, database

I'm building a simple Admin system for an Honours level University project.

Build on Codeigniter with MongoDB using the Alex Bible driver. I'm and trying to carry out a simple insert with hard coded values at the moment.

**My Model**

```
$username = "William";
        $email = "Test";
        
        $registerdata = array(
                "username"   => $username,
                "email"      => $email);
        
        $collection = 'students';
        
        $this->mongo_db->insert($collection, $registerdata);
```

Throwing the following errors:

> **PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: insert
>
> Filename: libraries/Mongo_db.php
>
> Line Number: 456

And:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: MongoCollection::insert(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, null given
>
> Filename: libraries/Mongo_db.php
>
> Line Number: 456

Any ideas?

It calls this function in the library if that helps any:

```
     * Insert a new document into the passed collection
     *
     *  @usage = $this->mongo_db->insert('foo', $data = array());
     */
    
     public function insert($collection = "", $data = array()) {
        if(empty($collection))
            show_error("No Mongo collection selected to insert into", 500);
        if(count($data) == 0 || !is_array($data))
            show_error("Nothing to insert into Mongo collection or insert is not an array", 500);
        
        try {
            $this->db->{$collection}->insert($insert, array('safe' => TRUE));
            if(isset($insert['_id']))
                return($insert['_id']);
            else
                return(FALSE);
        } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
            show_error("Insert of data into MongoDB failed: {$e->getMessage()}", 500);
        }
        
     }
```

Comment: That `insert` method looks a bit odd. It references a variable called `$insert` but I cannot see where it gets it from. Did you write that method? If so, maybe you meant `$data` instead?

Comment: The insert method I'm using comes from the MongoDB driver here : https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/README.md

Comment: https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong - I wonder if you have copied and pasted version 2 of this library without installing the whole thing? The new method is:

```
public function insert($collection = '', $insert = array(), $options = array())
```

Reinstall the library in your application and check the library files have been pulled in their entirety.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem, I haven't tried it yet but I know that's the issue, pulled y hair out for hours and couldn't see it for looking at it!!  Thank You :)

Comment: Great. It's worth regarding libraries as "non-editable" - having them as Git submodules or Composer dependencies helps avoid these library+edits problems `:)`.